# Trying to (slightly) generalize C++ template. Associative container Key:Value Inversion

Tags: c++, templates, refactoring

The goal of the function template below is to take any `unordered_map` and to produce a new `unordered_map` with the `key_type` and `mapped_type` inverted.
The function below works for `std::unorderd_map`. I'd like it to additionally work for EITHER `std::unordered_map` and any stl hashmap analog.

An additional benefit I'd like to maintain is that when calling the function, if default behavior is desired, `auto inversion = InvertHashMap(someIntStringMap)` works with no template arguments. However, if I do provide the valid initial template arguments, I can override the default hasher for example used to build the inverted map.

I am having profound difficulty making the container generic, while still providing default-able template arguments based on that container's 5 template arguments. As soon as I make the container itself a template argument, overload resolution fails and the compilation fails.

I've entertained making the associative container the only template argument, but then the ability to affect the output container's template arguments are lost, at least in the way they can be explicitly templated in my non-flexible example.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template <typename  InKeyType,
    typename  InValueType,
    typename  InHasher,
    typename  InEq,
    typename  InAlloc,
    typename  OutHash = std::hash<InValueType>,
    typename  OutEq = std::equal_to<InValueType>,
    typename OutAlloc=std::allocator<std::pair<constInValueType,InKeyType>>>

    std::unordered_map<InValueType, InKeyType, OutHash, OutEq, OutAlloc>
     InvertMap(const std::unordered_map<InKeyType, InValueType, InHasher, InEq, InAlloc>& source)
{
    std::unordered_map<InValueType, InKeyType, OutHash, OutEq, OutAlloc> outMap;
    for (const auto& sourceKVPair : source)
        outMap[std::get<1>(sourceKVPair)] = std::get<0>(sourceKVPair);

    return outMap;
}
//in a .cpp
unordered_map<int,string> um;
auto newUM = InvertHashMap(um);   //works well; newUM::key_type is string
```

I'd like to be able to call `InvertMap(aIntStringUnorderedMap)` and ALSO `InvertMap< int, string, hash<int>, ..., MyCustomStringHasher>(aIntStringHashMapLikeClass)//producing a HashMapLikeClass<string,int, MyCustomStringHasher,...defaults>`

TLDR: How do I introduce an argued container to a template, and also its template parameters, without changing call-site semantics?

Edit. This is my attempt to use the container as the only template argument.

```
template <typename AssocCont>
auto InvertCompliantHashMapThatIsntSTDUnorderedMap(const AssocCont&)
{
    typedef typename AssocCont::key_type InKeyType;
    typedef typename AssocCont::mapped_type InMappedType;
    typedef typename AssocCont::value_type InPairConstruct;
    typedef typename AssocCont::hasher InHasher;
    typedef typename AssocCont::key_equal InEq;
    //...
}
//But now there is no external means of desginating the new container's hasher,equality functor etc...
//And as it turns out, I cant even instantiate a new return object from AssocCont<InKeyType,InMappedType> since it is a distinct and unknown type
AssocCont<InMappedType,InKeyType> outmap = AssocCont<InMappedType,InKeyType>(); // nope. equivalent to object<key,value><otherkey,othervalue>()
```

DOUBLE EDIT: in my haste to provide an example, I chose `std::map` as an alternate paramater example, which i realize doesn't have a hasher, nor five template arguments. So the basis of my question is still trying to diversify this function, but **specifically for arguments that have five template arguments of their own with compatible behavior...**. I have edited my post to mitigate this oversight.

Comment: Can you use `std::map<T>::key_type` and `std::map<T>::mapped_type` (and same for `std::unordered_map<T>`)?

Comment: @crayzeewulf I tried that, but unfortunately, if the container's template arguments are not part of the template definition, the user can not override them. If the default allocator and hasher and equality functors are all desired, the container's being the only template parameter, and using scope penetration to get the relevant types would be fine. I only want to override outbound template parameters, but they're based on the input ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this might be better implemented in a manner similar to the [standard algorithms library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). In other words, design your inversion function to take a range of iterators into the input container and an iterator into the output container. It will be simpler to implement and provide greater flexibility to users. Furthermore, it will be somewhat independent of the container type as long as the input and output iterators satisfy certain conditions (imposed by [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/constraints) perhaps). Here is an example which may not be exactly what you want but you can probably modify it to fit your needs:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace
{
    template <class InputIt, class OutputIt>
    void inverse_map(InputIt start, InputIt stop, OutputIt d_first)
    {
        while(start != stop) 
        {
            *d_first = {start->second, start->first} ;
            ++d_first ;
            ++start ;
        }
    }
} // anonymous namespace

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> map_1 {{1, "foo"}, {2, "bar"}, {3, "foo"}} ;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> map_2 ;
    // 
    // Or, you can use:
    // 
    // std::unordered_map<std::string, int, MyCustomHasher> map_2 ;
    // 

    inverse_map(map_1.begin(), map_1.end(), std::inserter(map_2, map_2.end())) ;

    for(const auto& [key, value]: map_2) // requires C++17
        std::cout << key << ": " << value << "\n" ;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
bar: 2
foo: 1
```

Try it out online [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4730abf23f154d25).

Comment: I like this idea, but not as much as the one in my head. The elegance of `auto IntStringMap = InvertMap( StringIntMap);` is undenaiable. No need to predeclare the out container, or to paramaterize iterators of any kind. Turns out templates aren't magic entities that make C++ like a dynamic language, while sacrificing no performance. I guess I can create specialized versions for specific containers I know I want(like my example), and the iterator version for all other cases. Of course, there is always the option of just manually writing the process for the specific containers and types at hand.

Comment: @schulmaster I see your point. Like you, I've been tempted to implement container-based algorithms due to their apparent simplicity. However, time and again generalizing them has resulted in too many complications. I've eventually ended up with range based algorithms (such as those in the standard library) in most cases. [Here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/231336/why-do-all-algorithm-functions-take-only-ranges-not-containers/231351) is some discussion about this. C++ will soon have [Ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges) to simplify things.

Comment: One advantage, among many others, of using iterator-based approach is that it decouples algorithms from containers. So, the algorithms work with existing/intended containers as well as future/unintended containers. If you end up designing a completely new map class on your own that supports iterators, it is likely that the iterator-based implementation will work without any modifications. However, the container based approach will most likely need to be rewritten/refactored.